# Can i signin in Azure (or Microsoft 356 products) without Microsoft account?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, openid, saml, microsoft365

My client want use SSO for user authentication. He have a SSO service developed in Keycloack (SAML and OAuth/OpenId).
The SSO is connect with his Active Directory. Also Local Active Directory is connect with AD Azure by AD Connect. All users are federated (AD Local to AD Azure).
They want to log into the portal only with their service sso, **avoiding the login of Microsoft.**

It is obvious that you cannot log in to microsoft products without a microsoft account, **but I am looking for information that proves what I am saying.**

Answer (score 0):

You should consider Azure Active Directory B2C.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) you can find more information.